# Insert to table on conditions

Tags: sql, node.js, database

How can I check my database if the email is already registered to throw an error else proceed to insert to table the new account
this is what i got

```
IF Not Exists(
  SELECT EmailAddres FROM accountInfo WHERE accountInfo.EmailAddres = $3
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO accountInfo (FirstName, LastName, EmailAddres,Password)
VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4)
```

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: you should not check on query level, instead you should do at code level and then try to insert to DB with query. The approach you are trying is wrong. Else post your complete requirement and code you have with clear details..